# using loops for initialization result in faster time

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have this code:

```
def init_matr(r, c):

    matr = np.random.randint(2, size=(r, c))  
    return matr

def init_matr_loop(r, c):

    matr = np.zeros((r,c))

    for idx,i in enumerate(matr):
        matr[idx][0] = np.random.randint(2)
        matr[idx][1] = np.random.randint(2)

    return matr
```

With data:

```
r = 1000
c = 1000

%timeit -n 1000 init_matr(r, c) 
%timeit -n 1000 init_matr_loop(r, c)
```

I am receiving:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 8.17 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 556 µs per loop
```

where I can see that the loop version is faster!

Why is that?

With smaller size , `r=100, c=100` , the`init_matr` is faster as expected.

Comment: On my machine the first version runs in 4.1ms per loop and the second is 5ms per loop (with `r = c = 1000`). What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger:I am using 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matr = np.random.randint(2, size=(r, c))` creates r*c random values

This sets 2*r values:

```
for idx,i in enumerate(matr):
    matr[idx][0] = np.random.randint(2)
    matr[idx][1] = np.random.randint(2)
```

`for idx,i in enumerate(matr):` iterates on the rows of `matr`, so you are setting just 2 columns of `matr` to random values.

For large enough `c` the 2nd could be faster despite being iterative.  But they aren't doing the same thing, so it doesn't make much sense to compare them.

Were you by any chance trying to use `np.enumerate` instead?

Comment: Thanks!np.ndenumerate is still slower.